# Load a byte[] into an Image at Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a `byte[]` that is represented by an `Image`. I am downloading this `Image` via a `WebClient`. When the `WebClient` has downloaded the picture and I reference it using its URL, I get a `byte[]`. My question is, how do I load a `byte[]` into an `Image` element in WPF?  Thank you.

*Note*: This is complementary to the question I asked here: [Generate Image at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580359/generate-image-at-runtime). I cannot seem to get that approach to work, so I am trying a different approach.

Comment: Please note, I am looking to load a byte[] into a System.Windows.Controls.Image instance. Not a System.Drawing.Image instance as everyone has kindly pointed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx), and sets its [`StreamSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx) to a stream containing the binary data. If you want to make a `stream` from a `byte[]`, use a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx):

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

Answer (score 21):

Create a `BitmapImage` from the `MemoryStream` as below:

```
MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.StreamSource = byteStream;
image.EndInit();
```

And in XAML you can create an `Image` control and set the above `image` as the **`Source`** property.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net framework 4.0

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;

private Image GetImageFile(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
{
   if (postedFile == null) return null;
   return Image.FromStream(postedFile.InputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way that I figured out how to do it so that it was both fast and thread safe was the following:

```
 var imgBytes = value as byte[];
 if (imgBytes == null)
  return null;
 using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imgBytes))
   return BitmapFrame.Create(stream,BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
```

I threw that into a converter for my WPF application after running the images as Varbinary from the DB.