# Load byte[] into a System.Windows.Controls.Image at Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a byte[] that represents a .png file. I am downloading this .png via a WebClient. When the WebClient has downloaded the .png I reference via a URL, I get a byte[]. My question is, how do I load a byte[] into a System.Windows.Controls.Image element in WPF? Thank you.

Note: This is complementary to the question I asked here: [Load a byte[] into an Image at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582805/load-a-byte-into-an-image-at-runtime). I was not specific enough in my original question, but the answers were still relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [PngBitmapDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapdecoder.aspx). The docs show example usage.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers you got on the other question.. which should work fine, you should also be able to create a BitmapImage object and set the UriSource to the web URI instead of using a webclient and then set the Image.Source to the BitmapImage.. [See This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx)