# Convert system.windows.controls.image object to byte array

Tags: c#, wpf, image, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF Image to Byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553611/wpf-image-to-byte)
>   [Load byte[] into a System.Windows.Controls.Image at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583414/load-byte-into-a-system-windows-controls-image-at-runtime)

How do you convert a `system.windows.controls.image` object to byte array? This type is non-serializable hence you cannot use a `BinaryFormatter` to serialize it into a `MemoryStream` which is castable to a `byte[]`.

Comment: Why people always want to turn *controls* into byte arrays into is beyond me: [WPF Image to Byte Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553611/wpf-image-to-byte) (Voted to close but misclicked, the link in this comment should the correct duplicate)