# WPF BitmapImage Serialization/Deserialization

Tags: wpf, serialization, bitmapimage, deserialization

I've been trying to Serialize and Deserialize BitmapImages. I've been using methods which supposedly works which I found in this thread: [error in my byte[] to WPF BitmapImage conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886849/error-in-my-byte-to-wpf-bitmapimage-conversion)

Just to iterate what is going on, here is part of my Serialization code:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // This is a BitmapImage fetched from a dictionary.
                    BitmapImage image = kvp.Value; 

                    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
                    encoder.Save(ms);

                    byte[] buffer = ms.GetBuffer();

                    // Here I'm adding the byte[] array to SerializationInfo
                    info.AddValue((int)kvp.Key + "", buffer);
                }
```

And here is the deserialization code:

```
// While iterating over SerializationInfo in the deserialization
// constructor I pull the byte[] array out of an 
// SerializationEntry
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(entry.Value as byte[]))
                    {
                        ms.Position = 0;

                        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                        image.BeginInit();
                        image.StreamSource = ms;
                        image.EndInit();

                        // Adding the timeframe-key and image back into the dictionary
                        CapturedTrades.Add(timeframe, image);
                    }
```

Also, I'm not sure if it matters but earlier when I populated my dictionary I encoded Bitmaps with PngBitmapEncoder to get them into BitmapImages. So not sure if double-encoding has something to do with it. Here's the method that does that:

```
// Just to clarify this is done before the BitmapImages are added to the
// dictionary that they are stored in above.
private BitmapImage BitmapConverter(Bitmap image)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();
                bImg.BeginInit();
                bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
                bImg.EndInit();
                ms.Close();

                return bImg;
            }
        }
```

So the problem is, serialization and deserialization works fine. No errors, and the dictionary has entries with what seems to be BitmapImages, however their width/height and 
some other properties are all set to '0' when I look at them in debugging-mode. And of course, nothing is shown when I try to display the images.

So any ideas as to why they aren't properly deserialized?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You should not dispose MemoryStream, used from image initializing. Remove `using` in this line

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(entry.Value as byte[]))
```

2) After

```
encoder.Save(ms);
```

Try adding

```
ms.Seek(SeekOrigin.Begin, 0);
ms.ToArray();
```

Comment: Back again to help me today I see, you helped me with DeflateStreams yeseterday if you remember. Applied your changes and now it works perfectly, thanks again!

Comment: Fortune) It seems, that we do same alike things.

Comment: Looking for some clarification on this.  Was the solution to change ms.GetBuffer() to ms.GetArray() after seeking to the start?