# Serialize a System.Windows.Media.ImageSource object

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I am creating a chat application very basic. I establish the chat with a tcp connection. I often send serialized object through the network stream because it is simplier to program that way. anyways if I have a `class person{ public string name{get;set;} }` then it will be eassy to serialize that class.  when I include a `public ImageSource Img {get;set;}` I am not able to serialize that class person any more.

the way I serialize is as:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.name = \\some name
p.Img = \\ some image

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());

x.Serialize(connection.stream, p);//here is when the problem comes. I am not able to serialize it if I include an Img
```

Comment: Image to xml serialization is bit....strange

Comment: I don't mind using a different kind of serialization...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't serialize an image to XML, but you can save it to a `MemoryStream` and encode the binary data to base64.

```
string ImageToBase64(BitmapSource bitmap)
{
    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    var frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
    encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
    using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
    }
}

BitmapSource Base64ToImage(string base64)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    using(var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        return BitmapFrame.Create(stream);
    }
}
```

Note that base64 is not very efficient in terms of space... If possible, it would be better to transmit the image in binary form, rather than in XML.

Comment: and once I have the image as a string how do I convert it back to an image?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the `Base64ToImage` method - the stream gets disposed before `BitmapFrame` actually accesses it. I've described the fix in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424285/197913).

Comment: For deserializing, instead of BitmapFrame I ended up using BitmapImage (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685504/316760). The former returned the first image on subsequent calls (so, same image throughout my UI). I'm sure it was user error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

your approach is correct but does not work anymore as soon as the class `Person` contains any non serializable object like in your case the ImageSource.

If I had to solve it staying close to your solution, I would store the `byte[]` of the image and parse it back after deserialization to reconstruct the ImageSource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BinaryFormatter or available encoders like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.jpegbitmapencoder.aspx from [System.Windows.Media.Imaging Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608877.aspx). Also see [WPF BitmapImage Serialization/Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308777/wpf-bitmapimage-serialization-deserialization) . If you want to use string (xml) then i think the Base64 is the only way.