# C# Convert BitmapImage to Byte[] and vice-versa in Windows Store App

Tags: c#-4.0, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, bitmapimage

This question is specific to **Windows Store App (Windows 8)**.

I'm trying to convert a `Bitmapimage` to `Byte[]` and store it in a xml file, then retrieve and convert it back to `Bitmapimage`.

I was able to convert the `Bitmapimage` to `byte[]` (although it's not the best way, so I'm not including example). Then I'm using serialization to convert a class to xml. Here's the attribute used to serialize `byte[]`:

```
    private byte[] iconBytes;
    [XmlAttribute(DataType = "base64Binary")]
    public byte[] IconBytes
    {
        get 
        { 
            // TO DO: Convert BitmapImage to Byte[]
            return this.iconBytes; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            this.SetProperty(ref this.iconBytes, value);
            // TO DO: Convert Byte[] to BitmapImage
        }
    }
```

And here is the XML generated:

```
<MyApp xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Groups>
<Group Title="Group1">
  <Items>
    <Item Title="Item1" IconBytes="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" />
  </Items>
</Group>
</Groups>
</MyApp>
```

**Once I deserialize the class from the xml, how can I convert `byte[]` to `BitmapImage`?**

There are several examples out there addressing this issue, but they are all related to Silverlight and WPF, and none of them translate successfully to **Windows Store App (Windows 8)**.

Please keep in mind that examples using streams from the web or local computer does not apply to this issue. The image `byte[]` is already in memory because the data was deserialized from an xml file.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `InMemoryRandomAccessStream`:

```
var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await stream.WriteAsync(iconBytes.AsBuffer());
stream.Seek(0);

var image = new BitmapImage();
await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
```

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/winappswithcsharp/thread/4b2d1889-d4dd-4980-adef-540db2836239#921ae854-326e-4bba-9898-f5f9ff01ab57)'s another example.

Comment: Thanks @Damir for pointing me in the right direction, I found [another posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529301/load-bitmapimage-from-base64string?answertab=active#tab-top) that seems to work for the person that asked, still not working for me. I believe the Base64 string that I'm using is incorrect.
Any suggestions on how to convert a BitmapImage into Base64?

Comment: @YYZRichard I corrected my answer by adding a missing seek to the beginning of the memory stream. I have tested the code now and it works. I haven't managed to load the image from your XML, though. Indeed there seems to be something wrong with it, since no image viewer opens it up if I save it to a file. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13423796/197913) for a working `BitmapImage` to `Base64` conversion.

Comment: Thanks again @Damir, I added `Stream.Seek(0)`, and I'm now getting the error `The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)`, in the last line `await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);`

Comment: @YYZRichard Yes, this happens because the byte array is not a valid image as you already suggested yourself. If you try loading the byte array from a valid file, the same code will work. Did you check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262418/197913) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424285/197913) for a working conversion between `BitmapImage` and `Base64`?