# Why IsolatingStorageSettings is empty when i restart my APP ? (WP8)

Tags: memory, windows-phone-8, settings, isolatedstorage

I use the IsolatingStorageSetting to store a collection of objects. It works great when my app is running but when I restart it...the collection is empty...Why does it not keep my object collection in memory.?

```cs
 private  void llsElements_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            LongListSelector llselement = null;
            listElementCollection.Clear();

            if (sender != null)
                llselement =(LongListSelector)sender;

            if(llselement.SelectedItem!=null)
            {
               BdeskElement bdelement=(BdeskElement)llselement.SelectedItem;

               if (bdelement.TypeElement == BdeskElement.BdeskTypeElement.File)
               {

                   if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(bdelement.URLElement))//IsCached? =>NON
                   {

                       if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Count >= 100)//Si la liste des fichiers en cache est pleine
                       {
                           string KeyOldestElement = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Last().Key;
                           IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove(KeyOldestElement);//on supprime le dernier élément de la liste
                           if (IsolatedStorageOperations.IsFileSaved(KeyOldestElement+bdelement.Extension))
                           IsolatedStorageOperations.DeleteFile(KeyOldestElement+bdelement.Extension);

                       }

                       IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add(bdelement.URLElement, bdelement);//on ajoute notre élément

                        DownloadAndReadFile(bdelement);

                   }

                   else  //Si le fichier est deja présent dans la liste (donc déja en cache)
                   {
                       if (IsFileModified(bdelement, IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[bdelement.URLElement]))//compare la version téléchargée et la version en cache/ les versions sont identiques
                       {
                           string FileNameFormated = bdelement.URLElement.Replace("/", "_").Substring(7, bdelement.URLElement.Length - 7);
                           if (IsolatedStorageOperations.IsFileSaved(FileNameFormated))
                           {
                               MessageBox.Show("Le fichier est lu dans le cache");
                               byte[] Encryptedbytefile = IsolatedStorageOperations.GetFile((FileNameFormated));
                               byte [] UnCryptedByteFile=EncryptedString.DecryptDataToData(Encryptedbytefile);
                               IsolatedStorageOperations.SaveToFile(UnCryptedByteFile, "FileToRead" + bdelement.Extension);
                               IsolatedStorageOperations.ReadFile("FileToRead"+bdelement.Extension);

                           }

                       }

                       else//les versions sont différentes
                       {
                           IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove(bdelement.URLElement);//supprime l'ancienne version
                           IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add(bdelement.URLElement, bdelement);//ajoute la nouvelle

                           DownloadAndReadFile(bdelement);
                       }


                   }
               }
               else if (bdelement.TypeElement == BdeskElement.BdeskTypeElement.Folder)
               {

                   //l'élément cliqué devient l'élément courant
                   App.CurrentFolder = bdelement;
                   //On raffiche la page
                   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/Views/BDocs/FolderView.xaml?id={0}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), UriKind.Relative));

               }
            }
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save(); //EDITED
            }
```

*EDIT*

**ISSUE I HAVE ON THE SAVE METHOD**

Informations supplémentaires : Type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.

Comment: Images can be tricky to save. If you continue to have issues check out this free library. EZ_Iso.dll it has built in functionality for saving images. You only need to do one line calls. http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's because you aren't saving it - try to use [IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) when you finsh with it.

Of course it won't work when you restart the Emulator - after restarting it is a fresh instance.

**EDIT** - after OP's edit

You cannot serialize `ImageSource` - similar question is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/efb02058-cc35-4f48-9e6b-3f136b42fff6/systemwindowsmediaimagesource-cannot-be-serialized-error?forum=wpdevelop). Instead consider serializing ImagePath.

Comment: Ahah yeah 30 second after I posted this message I understood my mistake...but Im having an error that i don't understand...I edited the post...

Comment: Sorry i meant when i restart the APP...Oh damn my object has a property which is a BitmapImage...i guess the issue come from there..That's really annoying..:( Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @PaulMartinez Consider serializing ImagePath and if you really need to serialize Image, [this answer might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262418/2681948).