# Serialize bitmapImage and deserialize in class by XmlSerialize Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, serialization, xmlserializer, bitmapimage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF BitmapImage Serialization/Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308777/wpf-bitmapimage-serialization-deserialization)

I have class I have to seriazlize this class

```
class X{
....
public BitmapImage SomeImage{ get; set; }
....
}
```

That's my logic for serializing object

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(X));
 serializer.Serialize(way, person);
```

I'm using XmlIgnore attribute that not serialize image.But i Have to serialize picture.How I have to do it?Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to transform the BitmapImage in a byte[] and then serialize it to the XML. I'm doing it in my project and it works.

Here's how to do it: [WPF BitmapImage Serialization/Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308777/wpf-bitmapimage-serialization-deserialization)