# How to serialize a Class contains BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, deserialization, bitmapimage

I have a DeepCopy method, which serializes the object passed in parameter and returns back the deserialized object to make deep copy.

My method is:

```
public static class GenericCopier<T>
{     
           public static T DeepCopy(object objectToCopy)
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, objectToCopy);
                    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
                }
            }
}
```

It works well, if the object passed to the parameter doesn't contain any BitmapImage Field and Properties.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string TestString {get; set;}
  public BitmapImage TestImage { get; set;}
}
```

If I make DeepCopy of MyClass,

```
MyClass orginal = new MyClass(){ TestString = "Test"};
MyClass copy = GenericCopier<MyClass>.DeepCopy(orginal);
```

it throws exception

*Type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' in Assembly  is not marked as serializable*

I found a method to serialize BitmapImage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308777/wpf-bitmapimage-serialization-deserialization)

But, How can i mix the both type of serialization (BinaryFormatter & PngBitmapEncoder) to serialize MyClass?

Comment: I would suggest to store your image as byte[] field if its possible and then recreate it in property. Note that BinaryFormatter serializes only fields.

Comment: If i use byte[] type instead of BitmapImage , how can i bind byte[] in Source property of Image control in xaml?

Comment: use BitmapImage property where you reconstruct your image from a byte[] field in property getter, there examples how to reconstruct one from byte array. Also it won't be most optimal way for your case, you should reuse your images instead of copying them, some one could explain better

Comment: Sorry, but where is the sense in creating e deep copy of a bitmap? You should perhaps explain the use cases of your GenericCopier class. There are certainly better approaches than serialization.

Comment: Using serialization for cloning / copying is perhaps the most inefficient way. Don't use serialization unless you have to (e.g. domain or process boundaries crossing).

Comment: @Clemens I am mainly using this generic copier class for copying reference type list. If I use normal method for copying reference type list(using assignment operator (=)), the changes made in copied list reflects to original list.

Comment: Create a Clone method (e.g. implement the IClonable interface) in all the types that should be copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here:

**Option 1: Implement `ISerializable` and Snapshot to PNG**

What you must do here is have all classes that contain your `BitmapImage` implement the [`ISerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface, then, in [`GetObjectData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.getobjectdata(v=vs.110).aspx), return a byte array representing an encoding of the image, for instance PNG.  Then in the [deserialization constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182342.aspx) decode the PNG to a new `BitmapImage`.

*Note that this snapshots the image and thus may lose some WPF data.*

Since you may have multiple classes that contain a `BitmapImage`, the easiest way to do this is to introduce some wrapper struct with an implicit conversion from and to `BitmapImage`, like so:

```
[Serializable]
public struct SerializableBitmapImageWrapper : ISerializable
{
    readonly BitmapImage bitmapImage;

    public static implicit operator BitmapImage(SerializableBitmapImageWrapper wrapper)
    {
        return wrapper.BitmapImage;
    }

    public static implicit operator SerializableBitmapImageWrapper(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
    {
        return new SerializableBitmapImageWrapper(bitmapImage);
    }

    public BitmapImage BitmapImage { get { return bitmapImage; } }

    public SerializableBitmapImageWrapper(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
    {
        this.bitmapImage = bitmapImage;
    }

    public SerializableBitmapImageWrapper(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])info.GetValue("image", typeof(byte[]));
        if (imageBytes == null)
            bitmapImage = null;
        else
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.BeginInit();
                bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
                bitmap.EndInit();
                bitmapImage = bitmap;
            }
        }
    }

    #region ISerializable Members

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        byte [] imageBytes;
        if (bitmapImage == null)
            imageBytes = null;
        else
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BitmapImage.SaveToPng(ms);
                imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        info.AddValue("image", imageBytes);
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class BitmapHelper
{
    public static void SaveToPng(this BitmapSource bitmap, Stream stream)
    {
        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        SaveUsingEncoder(bitmap, stream, encoder);
    }

    public static void SaveUsingEncoder(this BitmapSource bitmap, Stream stream, BitmapEncoder encoder)
    {
        BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
        encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }

    public static BitmapImage FromUri(string path)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(path);
        bitmap.EndInit();
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    SerializableBitmapImageWrapper testImage;

    public string TestString { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage TestImage { get { return testImage; } set { testImage = value; } }
}

public static class GenericCopier
{
    public static T DeepCopy<T>(T objectToCopy)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, objectToCopy);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Use Serialization Surrogates to Clone the `BitmapImage` Directly**

It turns out that `BitmapImage` has a [`Clone()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, so it is reasonable to ask: is it somehow possible to override binary serialization to replace the original with a clone, without actually serializing it?  Doing so would avoid the potential data loss of snapshotting to PNG and would thus appear preferable.

In fact, this is possible using [serialization surrogates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx) to replace the bitmap images with an [`IObjectReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iobjectreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) proxy containing an ID of a cloned copy created by the surrogate.

```
public static class GenericCopier
{
    public static T DeepCopy<T>(T objectToCopy)
    {
        var selector = new SurrogateSelector();
        var imageSurrogate = new BitmapImageCloneSurrogate();
        imageSurrogate.Register(selector);

        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter(selector, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Clone));

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, objectToCopy);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }
    }
}

class CloneWrapper<T> : IObjectReference
{
    public T Clone { get; set; }

    #region IObjectReference Members

    object IObjectReference.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
    {
        return Clone;
    }

    #endregion
}

public abstract class CloneSurrogate<T> : ISerializationSurrogate where T : class
{
    readonly Dictionary<T, long> OriginalToId = new Dictionary<T, long>();
    readonly Dictionary<long, T> IdToClone = new Dictionary<long, T>();

    public void Register(SurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        foreach (var type in Types)
            selector.AddSurrogate(type, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Clone), this);
    }

    IEnumerable<Type> Types
    {
        get
        {
            yield return typeof(T);
            yield return typeof(CloneWrapper<T>);
        }
    }

    protected abstract T Clone(T original);

    #region ISerializationSurrogate Members

    public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var original = (T)obj;
        long cloneId;
        if (original == null)
        {
            cloneId = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!OriginalToId.TryGetValue(original, out cloneId))
            {
                Debug.Assert(OriginalToId.Count == IdToClone.Count);
                cloneId = OriginalToId.Count;
                OriginalToId[original] = cloneId;
                IdToClone[cloneId] = Clone(original);
            }
        }
        info.AddValue("cloneId", cloneId);
        info.SetType(typeof(CloneWrapper<T>));
    }

    public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        var wrapper = (CloneWrapper<T>)obj;
        var cloneId = info.GetInt64("cloneId");
        if (cloneId != -1)
            wrapper.Clone = IdToClone[cloneId];
        return wrapper;
    }

    #endregion
}

public sealed class BitmapImageCloneSurrogate : CloneSurrogate<BitmapImage>
{
    protected override BitmapImage Clone(BitmapImage original)
    {
        return original == null ? null : original.Clone();
    }
}
```

In this implementation, your main classes remain unchanged:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    BitmapImage testImage;

    public string TestString { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage TestImage { get { return testImage; } set { testImage = value; } }
}
```

Awkwardly, while `BitmapImage` has a `Clone` method, it does not actually implement the `ICloneable` interface.  If it had, the code above could look cleaner, because we could simply clone every cloneable object rather than calling a specific method for `BitmapImage`.

Comment: The Bitmap.Create function doesn't work for relative URI in my bitmap. I think i don't understand how images work in wpf.