# Customized Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I have some objects that must be serialized:

```
class Displayable{
  string name;
  Sprite icon;
}
```

The `icon` field requires custom serialization since `Sprite`s are already serialized (in different files, with their own format, by a game engine) and I only need to store a way to reference them (let's say a `string`, being the key inside a `Dictionary<string, Sprite>`).

Using `BinaryFormatter` I tried implementing `ISerializable` and `ISerializationSurrogate` but both of these methods create a new instance of the Sprite object on deserialization so they are not suitable for my case. I would like to have the same functionality of `ISerializationSurrogate` except I don't want the first parameter in `SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)` because I need to return an object I already have in memory instead of receiving a new instance from the deserializer and fill it with data.

I also tried external libraries like SharpSerializer but I don't like the constraints of having a public parameterless constructor and it doesn't really let you customize the serialization of special classes.
I've read about ProtoBuffers but that doesn't support inheritance and I need it somewhere else.

So my requirements are:

- Inheritance support
- Being able to define custom serialization for some types
- Deserialization of those custom types shouldn't create instances on it's own

Is there any library doing this?

Otherwise, am I being too picky? How do you usually achieve serialization of references to objects stored somewhere else?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
Here's what I'd like to have

```
public class SerializableSprite : ISerializationSurrogate
{
  public static Dictionary<string, Sprite> sprites;
  public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
    Sprite sprite = obj as Sprite;
    info.AddValue("spriteKey", sprite.name);
  }
  // The first parameter in this function is a newly instantiated Sprite, which I don't need
  public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector) {
    return sprites[info.GetString("spriteKey")];
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried binary serialization (through `BinaryFormmatter`)? It covers al your requirements. For instance, if the `Sprite` instance is shared between several object being serialized/deserialized, it will be serialized/deserialized just once - you don't need any custom logic for that.

Comment: Json.NET supports this via [`PreserveReferencesHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm) and [`TypeNameHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).  `DataContractSerializer` supports this via [`[DataContract(IsReference=true]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh241056.aspx) and [data contract known types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx).  But can you give details about what you have tried so far?  Your question seems like a recommendation question.

Comment: I know BinaryFormatter supports serialization by reference. In my case, Sprites are serialized somewhere else, meaning in different files and with a different format (by a game Engine, not my code). I just ensure to have them loaded BEFORE deserializing references to them. I also know how to manually serialize and deserialize these references, the only problem is I don't want new instances of Sprites on deserialization since I already have them in memory.

Comment: @dbc I tried implementing `ISerializable` and `ISerializationSurrogate` but both of these methods create a new instance of the Sprite object on deserialization so they are not suitable for my case. I would like to have the same functionality of `ISerializationSurrogate` except I don't want the first parameter in `SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)` because I need to return an object I already have in memory instead of receiving a new instance from the deserializer and fill it with data.

Comment: @dogiordano - **I tried implementing `ISerializable` and `ISerializationSurrogate`** - what serializer were you using when you did this?  Are you asking for recommendations for a replacement serializer or asking for help in correctly implementing `ISerializationSurrogate`?  If the latter, can you [edit] your question to show what serializer you are currently using and what you tried that failed?

Comment: I was using the `BinaryFormatter`. I've read how to implement `ISerializationSurrogate`, I just don't want it to create an instance on deserialization. So if there's a way to avoid this, I'd like to know that way. Otherwise, I'm asking for a replacement library. The point really is I don't want the Deserializer (whichever it is) to create an instance of the deserialized object since I didn't really serialized it on serialization.

Comment: @dogiordano - then you might want to narrow down your question into something specific about `BinaryFormatter`, and include a full [mcve] so we don't have to reconstruct your problem.  The general idea should be to use a surrogate class that implements `IObjectReference` as is shown in option 2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30702847/3744182).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to prevent `BinaryFormatter` from creating a new instance of `Sprite` during deserialization, during *serialization* you can call [`SerializationInfo.SetType(Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.settype(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify alternate type information -- typically some proxy type -- to insert into the serialization stream.  During deserialization `SetObjectData()` will be passed an instance of the proxy rather than the "real" type to initialize.  This proxy type must in turn implement [`IObjectReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iobjectreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that the "real" object can eventually be inserted into the object graph, specifically by looking it up in your table of sprites.

The following does this:

```
class ObjectReferenceProxy<T> : IObjectReference
{
    public T RealObject { get; set; }

    #region IObjectReference Members

    object IObjectReference.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
    {
        return RealObject;
    }

    #endregion
}

public sealed class SpriteSurrogate : ObjectLookupSurrogate<string, Sprite>
{
    static Dictionary<string, Sprite> sprites = new Dictionary<string, Sprite>();
    static Dictionary<Sprite, string> spriteNames = new Dictionary<Sprite, string>();

    public static void AddSprite(string name, Sprite sprite)
    {
        if (name == null || sprite == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        sprites.Add(name, sprite);
        spriteNames.Add(sprite, name);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Sprite> Sprites
    {
        get
        {
            return sprites.Values;
        }
    }

    protected override string GetId(Sprite realObject)
    {
        if (realObject == null)
            return null;
        return spriteNames[realObject];
    }

    protected override Sprite GetRealObject(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return null;
        return sprites[id];
    }
}

public abstract class ObjectLookupSurrogate<TId, TRealObject> : ISerializationSurrogate where TRealObject : class
{
    public void Register(SurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        foreach (var type in Types)
            selector.AddSurrogate(type, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All), this);
    }

    IEnumerable<Type> Types
    {
        get
        {
            yield return typeof(TRealObject);
            yield return typeof(ObjectReferenceProxy<TRealObject>);
        }
    }

    protected abstract TId GetId(TRealObject realObject);

    protected abstract TRealObject GetRealObject(TId id);

    #region ISerializationSurrogate Members

    public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var original = (TRealObject)obj;
        var id = GetId(original);
        info.AddValue("id", id);
        // use Info.SetType() to force the serializer to construct an object of type ObjectReferenceWrapper<TRealObject> during deserialization.
        info.SetType(typeof(ObjectReferenceProxy<TRealObject>));
    }

    public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        // Having constructed an object of type ObjectReferenceWrapper<TRealObject>, 
        // look up the real sprite using the id in the serialization stream.
        var wrapper = (ObjectReferenceProxy<TRealObject>)obj;
        var id = (TId)info.GetValue("id", typeof(TId));
        wrapper.RealObject = GetRealObject(id);
        return wrapper;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then apply it to a `BinaryFormatter` as follows:

```
        var selector = new SurrogateSelector();
        var spriteSurrogate = new SpriteSurrogate();
        spriteSurrogate.Register(selector);

        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter(selector, new StreamingContext());
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kBa0Rs).

**Update**

While the code above works in .Net 3.5 and above, it apparently does not work in [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d) despite compiling successfully there because of some problem with `IObjectReference`.  The following also works in .Net 3.5 and above and also avoids the use of `IObjectReference` by returning the real object from [`ISerializationSurrogate.SetObjectData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogate.setobjectdata(v=vs.110).aspx).  Thus it should work in unity3d as well (confirmed in comments):

```
public sealed class SpriteSurrogate : ObjectLookupSurrogate<string, Sprite>
{
    static Dictionary<string, Sprite> sprites = new Dictionary<string, Sprite>();
    static Dictionary<Sprite, string> spriteNames = new Dictionary<Sprite, string>();

    public static void AddSprite(string name, Sprite sprite)
    {
        if (name == null || sprite == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        sprites.Add(name, sprite);
        spriteNames.Add(sprite, name);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Sprite> Sprites
    {
        get
        {
            return sprites.Values;
        }
    }

    protected override string GetId(Sprite realObject)
    {
        if (realObject == null)
            return null;
        return spriteNames[realObject];
    }

    protected override Sprite GetRealObject(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return null;
        return sprites[id];
    }
}

public abstract class ObjectLookupSurrogate<TId, TRealObject> : ISerializationSurrogate where TRealObject : class
{
    class SurrogatePlaceholder
    {
    }

    public void Register(SurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        foreach (var type in Types)
            selector.AddSurrogate(type, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All), this);
    }

    IEnumerable<Type> Types
    {
        get
        {
            yield return typeof(TRealObject);
            yield return typeof(SurrogatePlaceholder);
        }
    }

    protected abstract TId GetId(TRealObject realObject);

    protected abstract TRealObject GetRealObject(TId id);

    #region ISerializationSurrogate Members

    public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var original = (TRealObject)obj;
        var id = GetId(original);
        info.AddValue("id", id);
        // use Info.SetType() to force the serializer to construct an object of type SurrogatePlaceholder during deserialization.
        info.SetType(typeof(SurrogatePlaceholder));
    }

    public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        // Having constructed an object of type SurrogatePlaceholder, 
        // look up the real sprite using the id in the serialization stream.
        var id = (TId)info.GetValue("id", typeof(TId));
        return GetRealObject(id);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Sample [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PEGeiP).

Comment: Thank you, this seems exactly what I was looking for. I'll test it soon and give feedback.

Comment: @dogiordano - answer updated with an alternate version that might work on unity3d as well as .net.

Comment: Wow... It worked! You've been far more than useful. I don't know how to thank you. I'd upvote you more if I could.