# Loading WPF Image control from byte array

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Hey, I am trying to load an `Image` control from a byte array, I've tried multiple solutions found online (particularly this site) but nothing seems to work.
My main goal was to obtain an `ImageSource` from the byte array and return it from a converter.

I've tried:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(lBytes);
bi.EndInit();
```

But this fails with:

> NotSupportedException
>
> No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.

Also tried first loading a `Bitmap` and from there try to get the `ImageSource`.

```
using (MemoryStream lMem = new MemoryStream(lBytes))
{
        TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap));
        System.Drawing.Bitmap b = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(lBytes);
        lResult = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            b.GetHbitmap(),
            IntPtr.Zero,
            System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        b.Dispose();
}
```

But this fails on the `ConvertFrom` with "Parameter is not valid."

All of this when loading a valid PNG file in my filesystem.

I am running out of ideas, any clue?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Alright, the problem was my way of loading the file...

I was using

```
using (FileStream lFileStream = new FileStream(pFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (StreamReader lReader = new StreamReader(lFileStream))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            string lString = lReader.ReadToEnd();
            bf.Serialize(ms, lString);
            ms.Seek(0, 0);
            lImage = ms.ToArray();
        } 
        lResult = new Graphic(lImage);
    }
}
```

But then read that I could use:

```
lImage = File.ReadAllBytes(pFilePath);
```

And that's it.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks OK, but maybe the stream does not have an expected format. Take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886849/error-in-my-byte-to-wpf-bitmapimage-conversion.

Comment: Also this blog post might be of help: http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/wpf-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard/

Comment: I don't know what to do about this format, I am just loading from a file and using the whole byte array as parameter, shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: @So Many Goblins, could you post the image here?

Comment: Also, how do you load the byte[] from the file?

Comment: The problem was in the way the byte array was being loaded.

Comment: oh, wow, that was a very complicated way of reading the bytes ;)

Comment: But use serialize seem wrong!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solution works correctly but I think your problem is about how to read array byte not how to convert the array to bitmap.
I've used that solution many times. The difference between my solution and your solution is how to read the file and convert it to an array.

I simply use:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)
```

Comment: Indeed, that is what I used :)